# How can I compress/short firebase email verification link. (iOS Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, email-validation

In firebase manage user docs I can't find any way to compress or short the length of email verification link. Functionality is working fine but this link looks so long and weird as user perspective. I've searched on the internet but not found any solution. Below is my code please code:

```
var actionCodeSettings =  ActionCodeSettings.init()
actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = false
let user = FirebaseAuthenticationHandler.shared.currentFirebaseUser
actionCodeSettings.url = URL.init(string:  String(format: "https://example.firebaseapp.com/?verifyemail=%@", user.email!))
actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
user.sendEmailVerification(with: actionCodeSettings, completion: { (error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("\(error?.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        print("Verfication email sent")
    }
```

And this the screenshot of link I'm receiving: [image: Click Here for Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried Firebase DynamicLinks

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am looking for a solution as well.

Comment: @IbrahimBroachwala I have posted a article on this topic after achieving this, please check it. I hope you will find you solution: https://medium.com/@huzaifa.ameen229/firebase-email-link-authentication-ac2504068562